# suppressing warning for overflow with Simulink "Shift Arithmetic" block

Tags: matlab, overflow, simulink

I'm using the Simulink R2012a [Shift Arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/shiftarithmetic.html) block to calculate `x << 2` where x is a 16-bit fixed-point Q15 number of type`fixdt(1,16,15)`.

Overflow is not a bug in this particular case. (I want values 0, 16384 = 0.5, -16384 = -0.5, and -32768 = -1.0 all to map into the value 0.)

The problem is that I get an overflow warning spew out of the command console for each instance this occurs:

```
 Warning: Overflow occurred. This originated from 'foo/bar/baz/Shift Arithmetic'.
```

I want to disable overflow warnings for a particular set of blocks only (the ones where this shift behavior is intentional), not for all blocks in general or even all Shift Arithmetic blocks. How can I do this?

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to switch off warnings for a particular set of blocks, the only option is to do it for the entire model.

Comment: bleah. sounds like a missing feature in Simulink. Somehow I need to tell it that overflow in a particular block is intentional.

Comment: Your only option might be to use a larger fixed point data type, check the value and perform the wrapping yourself when it overflows 16-bits.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a simple block, a solution may be to build your own block that won't trigger a warning.

EDIT:
I tried with 'Matlab Function'

```
function y = fcn(u)
y = bitshift(u, 2, 8);
```

I have the same result as with a shift block of 2 bits left with input 255 and types uint8 but no warning.

Comment: such as...... ? I agree but that's not really helpful. Bit shifting is a primitive operation and it's often difficult to replace primitive operations by other combinations of primitive operations.

Comment: Please see my edit. Warnings doesn't seem to be linked to the primitive but to the block.

Comment: Hmm, I'll give that a try. I need to use this model for embedded code generation also, not sure how it works when you have Matlab function blocks; the conservative approach would be to give up for code generation (no guarantee of running MATLAB code on an embedded system) but who knows.

Comment: I think that in a simple case like that the generated C code will be the same (at least not MATLAB code + an interpreter ...). It's easy to check in the C code with the block references in comments.